# training a custom estimator in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow and trying to train a custom CNN estimator with inputs being provided from `TFRecord` files.

The `Load_input()` function is supposed to look into **DATA_DIR** for `TFRecords` file and decode it through a call to `read_and_decode` function(which is supposed to do the actual decoding of the records), store the information into an instance of **_image_object** and return it.

`cnn_model` is where I have defined the CNN architecture. And `generate_input_fn` is supposed to create the batches and feed it to the `estimator.train` while training.

I just have an abstract understanding of the codes, no idea of the internal mechanics which is the primary reason why I am not able to debug.

Here is my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
import os 



DATA_DIR = "./TFRecords/train"  #path to tfrecords directory
TRAINING_SET_SIZE = 3
BATCH_SIZE = 3
IMAGE_SIZE = 224


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

# image object from protobuf
class _image_object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = tf.Variable([], dtype = tf.string)
        self.height = tf.Variable([], dtype = tf.int64)
        self.width = tf.Variable([], dtype = tf.int64)
        self.filename = tf.Variable([], dtype = tf.string)
        self.label = tf.Variable([], dtype = tf.int32)

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    # this module is responsible for extracting the features
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features = {
        "image/encoded": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "image/height": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/width": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/filename": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "image/class/label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),})
    image_encoded = features["image/encoded"]
    image_raw = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_encoded, channels=3)
    image_object = _image_object()
    image_object.image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image_raw, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)#resizes and crops
    image_object.height = features["image/height"]
    image_object.width = features["image/width"]
    image_object.filename = features["image/filename"]
    image_object.label = tf.cast(features["image/class/label"], tf.int64)
    return image_object

def Load_input():

    print 'Generating data from tfrecords...'
    filenames = [os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "train-0000%d-of-00002.tfrecord" % i) for i in xrange(0, 1)]

    for f in filenames:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
            raise ValueError("Failed to find file: " + f)
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    print 'decoding queue contents ::{}'.format(filename_queue)
    image_object = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image_object.image)
#    image = image_object.image
#    image = tf.image.adjust_gamma(tf.cast(image_object.image, tf.float32), gamma=1, gain=1) # Scale image to (0, 1)
    label = image_object.label
    filename = image_object.filename
    return image,label,filename


def cnn_model(features,labels,mode):

    print 'creating layers...'  
    #Input layer
    #inp = tf.reshape(features['x'],[-1,28,28,1])
    inp = tf.reshape(features,[-1,224,224,3])
    print 'input shape ::{}'.format(inp.shape)
    #convolutional layer #1
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=inp,filters=32,kernel_size=[5,5],padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print 'convolution-1 shape ::{}'.format(conv1.shape)

    #pooling Layer
    pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)
    print 'Pool-1 shape ::{}'.format(pool1.shape)
    #convolutional layer #2
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,filters=64,kernel_size=[5,5],padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print 'convolution-2 shape ::{}'.format(conv2.shape)
    #pooling layer
    pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)
    print 'Pool-2 shape ::{}'.format(pool2.shape)
    #dense layer
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2,[-1,56*56*64]) #dimension = [BATCH_SIZE,HEIGHT*WIDTH*CHANNELS of the last pooled layers]
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat,units=1024,activation=tf.nn.relu) # units = number of neurons per layer
    dropout=tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense,rate=0.4,training = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))

    #Logits Layer
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout,units=2) #has shape [batch_size, no_of_labels]
    predictions ={'classes':tf.argmax(input=logits,axis=1),'probabilities':tf.nn.softmax(logits,name='softmax_tensor')}
    print 'Logits shape ::{}'.format(logits.shape)
    print 'Labels shape ::{}'.format(labels.shape)

    #Calculate loss for TRAIN and EVAL mode
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels,logits=logits)

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss,global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    print 'Layers created...'
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,train_op=train_op)



def generate_input_fn(image,label,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):
   print("Filling queue with images before starting to train. " "This will take a few minutes.")
   num_preprocess_threads = 1
   def _input_fn():
      image_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,224,224,3])
      label_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.int64,shape=[batch_size,1])
      image_batch, label_batch= tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image_placeholder, label_placeholder],
            batch_size = batch_size,
            num_threads = num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity = 8 * BATCH_SIZE,
            min_after_dequeue = 4 * BATCH_SIZE)
      return image_batch, label_batch 
   return _input_fn



def main(unused_argv):
    print 'program started...'
    image_data, label_data, filename = Load_input()
    print 'image_data::{} label_data::{}'.format(type(image_data),type(label_data))

    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model,model_dir='./')
    print 'Estimator ready...'
    tensors_to_log = {'probabilities':'softmax_tensor'}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log,every_n_iter=1)
    print 'Logs ready...'
    print 'Starting training...'
    estimator.train(input_fn=generate_input_fn(image=image_data, label=label_data),steps=2,hooks=[logging_hook])


if __name__=='__main__':
  tf.app.run()
  print 'Program ended...'
```

it gives me the following error :

> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 9 and 3. Shapes are [9,2] and [3,3]. for 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg' (op: 'SoftmaxCross
>   EntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [9,2], [3,3].

also the layers shapes are as follows :

```
conv1 output shape :: (9, 224, 224, 32)
pool1 shape :: (9, 112, 112, 32)
conv2 shape ::(9, 112, 112, 64)
pool2 shape :: (9, 56, 56, 64)
Logits shape :: (9, 2)
Labels shape :: (3, 3)
```

I don't understand why is the `batch size` **9** even if I try to explicitly set it to **3** in the code.

**Note** : If anyone has a better/easier solution please post it. The aim is to **use tfrecords to train a custom CNN**

Comment: Unrelated note: There is no need to create variables in _image_object class. You will get a bunch of unused empty variables.

Comment: I would try to reduce your code as much as possible. It take a while to read it. What is the input shape `print 'input shape ::{}'.format(inp.shape)`?

Comment: A better alternative is to use tf.data API. There is an example of how to use it with Estimator in the 'Using high-level APIs' section in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

Comment: @iga, it is supposed to be `[BATCH_SIZE,224,224,3]`

Comment: I can see that this is  your expectation, but what is the actual size when program runs? If the first dimension is 9, you know what the problem happens before the `cnn_model` is called.

Comment: @iga,  tried `BATCH_SIZE=2`, interestingly now it gives `ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 4 and 2. Shapes are [4,2] and [2,2]. for 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg' (op: 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') wit
h input shapes: [4,2], [2,2].` It looks like whatever value I set it is squared

Comment: The `TFRecords` were created from a folder `demo` which contained two subfolders `dogs` & `cats` where each subfolder contains 3 pictures of the respective animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was at `generate_input_fn`.

Modify :

```
image_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,224,224,3])
label_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.int64,shape=[batch_size,1])
```

to :

```
image_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=image.shape)
label_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.int64,shape=label.shape)
```

i.e they should contain the dimension of a single image instance, because that's what is required by `tensors` argument of [tf.train.shuffle_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch)